# CDAP - embebing staring-timestamp logic inside a pipeline

Tags: pipeline, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I have a pipeline that makes a request to an API. And I would like to parametrize the start- and end-timestamps in the URL inside the http-plugin.

End-timestamp is -2hours from runtime, so it would be kind of easy to use a macro with the function `logicalStartTime` without giving a date-format and with a delta of -2 hours, and then get the corresponding timestamp.

But for the start-timestamp it's necessary to use the first day in current month/year at 00:00. And that's not so straight forward because, it would be necessary to use further functions, that are actually not allowed inside a macro (https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/1188036697/Macros+and+macro+functions#Macro-functions)

I've tried to put that runtime argument in the context through a "python transform"-plugin, but I think it is not developed to be run the first one in the pipeline (so the timestamp is available for the http-plugin).

I guess the arguments might be given through an orchestrator like airflow/cloud composer or through the "arg setter"-plugin. But for my understanding, it makes more sense to put that starting-timestamp logic inside the pipeline.

Does someone have an idea of how would it be possible, without needing to develop a new plugin? Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Hi, only options I can think of are 1) pass the start time through trigger (airflow/cloud composer for example) or 2) write an action plugin (should be easier to write where you need to put the argument value in context similar to https://github.com/data-integrations/argument-setter/blob/develop/src/main/java/io/cdap/plugin/ArgumentSetter.java#L77) and use that in the beginning of pipeline.

Comment: Hi Sagar, I've tried the second approach and it didn't work out; when I run the pipeline, I'm still asked about the argument-values I was supposed to set inside the plugin. After setting the argument name and value `context.getArguments().set("startTimestamp", startTimestampStr);`, shouldn't be the `context` passed/returned somewhere else?

Comment: I´ve just realized, that the arguments actually were set fine, but are not registered in the logs (`Pipeline 'HTTP_to_file_GCS_TimeStamp_ArgSetter' is started by user 'root' with arguments {logical.start.time=1640010516007}`) and you need to ignore the request of giving them a value, at the time of running the pipeline (deploy the pipeline and push run, a small window pops-up with the args without a value. The point there is not giving a value and just push run)